# I am struggling to understand how to show the cut-off frequency

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-filter, frequency-response

I understand that the cut-off frequency f = 1/(2πRC) or 70.7% from the maximum.

The issue I have is I don't understand how these end up being 2 different points on my graph.

[image]

Above is the cut-off frequency location based off the cut-off equation, but below is the point where if I took 70.7% of my maximum, the point should lie.

[image]

I don't get it. Is there something I am missing? If someone could please explain this would be quite helpful.

Below is an image of the circuit:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I believe the the issue is with the numbers you entered into the equation for #1 but also where you are measuring from #2

the equation is \$ f = \frac{1}{2\cdot \pi \cdot R \cdot C} = \frac{1}{2\cdot \pi \cdot 1000 \cdot 100e-9}  = 1.59kHz \$

From graph #1 you have the frequency closer to 15kHz and thus I believe the value or R or C was a factor of 10 too small

Looking at graph #2 you have the attenuation at 0.6 and the frequency is around 2kHz, if the cursor was moved to the left so the attenuation was closer to 70% you should read ~ 1.5kHz

Comment: Thank you I should of double checked my equation first. But I dont understand what you mean about the #2 graph, whats attenuation? I havent heard of it before?

Comment: sorry, attenuation means "loss of signal" and we generally describe filter response in terms of attenuation. If you look at graph #2 you have the cursor at 0.6 (60% attenuation) when it should be at 0.7 (70% attenuation).  Presently Graph #2 has a frequency of 2.1296kHz, if the cursors were moved to align with 70% attenuation the frequency should be 1.59kHz

Comment: Ah ok but when I calculated based on the 70% thats where it put the point, as my Maximum or the starting value was at 846.7, so I just multiplied that by 0.70 and got the value of 598.63 and that was the closest I could get.

Comment: The problem is that your graph starts at a frequency that's too high, and it isn't showing you the true maximum. Try starting your analysis at 10 Hz instead of 1000 Hz.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you, Ill get the simulation to try and start at a lower frequency

Answer (score -1):

You should start a sweep from 0Hz (DC), the V1 shall be sine wave and not pulse.

Your diagram starts at 1kHz, so where is the beginning? You could use log scale for better representation. MY guess is, that the starting amplitude is 1.0 and then it lowers to 0.707 at cca. 1.5kHz as you can see from the diagram.

Comment: First, AC analysis is based on sine waves, regardless of the source shown for transient analysis. Second, the graph is already using a logarithmic frequency scale, and you can't start at DC -- but you do need to start at a frequency that's low enough to show all of the features of interest.

Comment: @DaveTweed okeydokey, I have left my glasses somewhere, I am struggling for several days to find them without success. So, the scale is log, for the rest I am not familiar with the simulation software the OP is using.